# strip "\n" only from some lines in text file

Tags: python

I have a text file organized like this:

```
NAME: name\n
AGE: age\n
NOTES: random text\n
JOB: text
\n
NAME: name\n
AGE: age\n
NOTES: random text\n
JOB: text
\n
```

**I only wrote 5 lines for each block of data but let's say I have 7 lines or more. I also wrote only 2 blocks here but my file may contain over 100, and my desired output would be a list of lists**(preferably):

```
list=[[NAME: name\n, AGE: age\n, NOTES: random text\n, JOB: blabla, \n], [NAME: name\n, AGE: age\n, NOTES: random text\n, JOB: blabla, \n], [...]]
```

that I obtain with this code:

```
list_of_lists = [list[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(list),4)]
```

but my problem is that sometime the `random text` into `NOTES:` contains extra `\n` and may cause the grouping to be wrong:

```
list=[[NAME: name\n, AGE: age\n, NOTES: unwanted\n, newlines\n], [that ruin\n, my plans\n, \n, NAME: name\n] etc etc]
```

**So basically all lines are ok, the problem is the NOTES one where people inserted some carriage that I don't want because they make the text into NOTES to be split into different lines in the text and different items in the list: I want to delete \n in order to have the NOTES field grouped in one line (in the text) and in one item (in the list)**

> EDIT: Thanks for helping! I have tried some your solutions but still didn't solve my problem... So I edited my question to explain better (edited content in bold).

Comment: The `\n` characters aren't really part of the lines, but you could look at the beginning of every line and append it to the previous one if it doesn't start with `NAME:`, `AGE:`, or `NOTES:`. But I would suggest putting it all in a dictionary.

Comment: @L3viathan - The `\n` character is indeed part of the line it's on. It's a character like any other.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 While it is a character like any other, it is what makes the lines lines in the first place. E.g. in `NOTES: this\nis\ntesting` the second `\n` can't possibly be considered part of the _first_ line.

Comment: In problematic case what is content of your `NOTE:`. You can first split text with '\n\n'. This will give you chunk of text, then get each line from each chunk as required.

Comment: It is used as a sentinel value, but it is a character like every other character and is part of the line it's on. There isn't a line, and then a linefeed, and then a line, then a linefeed, etc. - each line simply has a linefeed character at the end, which defines the lines.

Comment: And if you're doing things like `NOTES: this\nis\ntesting` it doesn't make sense to talk about lines at all. It's just a string of characters. Various programs simply use `\n` as an invisible character that determines when to move the carriage back. The OP's code is simply showing those invisible characters, like many editors allow. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more clear now. I wonder if it's possible to do a loop that read every line and modifies the lines after NOTES that contain carriage back and pass on other lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

# some example text:
my_text = """NAME: name\nAGE: age\nNOTES: random text\n\nNAME: name\nAGE: age\nJOB: job\nNOTES: random text\n\nblah \n\n blah\n\nNAME: name\nAGE: age\nNOTES: more \n random\n text\n\n""" 
# splitting up your text into a list of lists:
my_list = [[c.group(1) for c in re.finditer('(?ms)(?=(^[A-Z]+:.*?)(^[A-Z]+:|\Z))',chunk.group(1))] for chunk in re.finditer('(?ms)(?=(^NAME:.*?)(^NAME:|\Z))', my_text)]
```

This works by performing two regex searches. The first one finds all the text starting from `NAME:` up until right before the next `NAME:` or the end of the file. This essentially splits the text into your data for each person. Then, an almost identical regex is used to split each of these into lists of each attribute (`NAME`, `AGE`, `JOB`, etc.).  This regex assumes that each attribute label is in all caps, occurs at the beginning of a line, and is followed by a `:`.

The contents of `my_list` in the example above is:

```
[['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: random text\n\n'],
 ['NAME: name\n',
  'AGE: age\n',
  'JOB: job\n',
  'NOTES: random text\n\nblah \n\n blah\n\n'],
 ['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: more \n random\n text\n\n']]
```

Comment: Thanks @bunji. I've tried your code, it returns `File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 186, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`
I wrote `my_text=open(file.txt, 'r')`

Comment: `my_text` should be the contents of the file as a string not the file object itself.  Try this:  `my_text = open('file.txt', 'r').read()`

Comment: it works great! I had never used re before..time to learn it I guess. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. If you are just getting into regular expressions I'd recommend playing around with [this site](https://regex101.com/) which lets you test out your code and get a feel for what regular expressions can do, or [this one](https://www.debuggex.com/) which is similar but also has a nice visual component. Happy regexing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing things a little bit differently:

```
result = []
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("NAME:"):
            if d:
                result.append(d)
            d = {}
        if any(line.startswith(key) for key in ("NAME:", "AGE:", "NOTES:")):
            key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
            d[key] = value
        else:
            d["NOTES"] += d["NOTES"] + line.strip()
    result.append(d)
```

This returns something like

```
[{'NOTES': ' random text random text', 'AGE': ' age', 'NAME': ' name'}, {'NOTES': ' random text random textother text. random text random textother text.', 'AGE': ' age', 'NAME': ' name'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is intended to be a key value pair, Therefore first try splitting up the data into a list of dictionaries.

You can reverse the text file string using `text[::-1]` and then do a replace `reverse_text.split(':EMAN')` then reversing again the strings within the lists. This should give you a list ready for parsing into a dict looking like:

```
list = [
    ['NAME: name\n AGE: age\n NOTES: random text\n\n'],
    ['NAME: name\n AGE: age\n NOTES: random text\n\n'],
    ...,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using *list comprehension* as:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myfile = StringIO("""NAME: name\n
AGE: age\n
NOTES: random text\n
\n
NAME: name\n
AGE: age\n
NOTES: random text\n
\n""")    # StringIO creates file like object

# You list comprehesion expression 
my_list = [["{}\n".format(item) for item in group.split("\n\n")+['']] for group in myfile.read().split("\n\n\n\n")]
#                               For adding extra `\n` at the end ^                              ^
```

where `my_list` will hold:

```
[['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: random text\n', '\n'], ['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: random text\n', '\n\n', '\n']]
```

In case you do not want `\n\n` as the second last element in the last sub-list, you may explicitly delete it as:

```
del my_list[-1][-2]
```

Now your `my_list` will hold the value:

```
[['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: random text\n', '\n'], ['NAME: name\n', 'AGE: age\n', 'NOTES: random text\n', '\n']]
```